# How to save large data send from logstash to Redis with list type?

Tags: list, redis, logstash, limit, pipeline

I'm using logstash to send data to Redis as

```
output {
  redis {
    host => ["${REDIS_URL}"]
    data_type => "list"
    key => "ID"
    codec => line { format => "%{id}"}
  }
}
```

When I check data in Redis, it created an `ID` list with 10000 records data in `DB0`. But the real data is much than 10000 records. Is it the limit number in Redis? How to deal with other data in a list of DB with Redis?

If 10000 is a limit in Redis, can I use other db like `DB1` to save other data?

Comment: There is no such limit, perhaps it's a logstash limit. Can you check the redis `MONITOR` and verify all the records got in?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Is it compulsory for some reason to use Redis list? As you said the data is much more than 10k, your fetch and other operations becoming O(n) will become a problem. If you share the problem statement, maybe there might be a better way to store the data in redis.

Comment: It was the limitation in `input` of logstash. @AnkitSahay I just want to save ID to Redis for other purpose. If there is no problem with large data even more than 10k or 100k, it's useful and possible in this case.

Comment: @iooi If the IDs are unique, I recommend you use set instead of lists, that way your fetch results will be a lot faster

Comment: @AnkitSahay Thank you. But from logstash, it only support `list` and `channel` data types: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-redis.html#plugins-outputs-redis-data_type. So I saved it with list type directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limitation in Redis. It was because of my `input` setting in logstash.

```
input {
  jdbc {
    ...
    jdbc_page_size => 10000
    jdbc_paging_enabled => true
  }
}
```